# How to catch an array .filter before moving onto .forEach?

Tags: javascript, filter, foreach

I have some code that filters an array based on search queries. This works fine but I want to run a function if there are no matches to any/one of the filters.

Filter Code:

```
function filter() {
    let filters = "";
    let checkboxDiv = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
    let inputs = checkboxDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");

    let postcode = document.getElementById("postcodeInput").value;
    let suburb = document.getElementById("suburbInput").value;
    suburb = suburb.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + suburb.slice(1);
    let capacity = document.getElementById("capacityInput").value;
    let results = Object.keys(halls);

    results.filter(key => {
        if (postcode == halls[key]['Location'][3]['Postcode'] && suburb == "") {filters += "Postcode "; return true;}
        if (suburb == halls[key]['Location'][1]['Suburb'] && postcode == "") {filters += "Suburb "; return true;};
        if (capacity <= halls[key]['Room'][0]['Standing Capacity'] && capacity != "") {filters += "Capacity ";return true;}
        return false
    }).forEach(key => filterAll([halls[key]]));
}
```

How might I 'catch' the filter statement if it returns false and run a function?

In english:
If user inputs a suburb, and there are no suburbs that match that, run function.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can't - since `.forEach` doesn't "know" what happened in `.fileter` - it only has access to entries that are "allowed" by the `.filter`

Comment: You cannot stop the `filter` before moving into the `forEach` because the `forEach` is immediately chained after the `filter`. You would have to break it up

Comment: How might I go about breaking it up? I'm not very experienced with methods,(I think they're called that) could I run a function instead of for each and have an if statament and then the forEach in that function??